# Are queries logged in a SQL Server Transaction log?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I do not clearly understand the relationship between single queries and the transaction log.

Let's say I never execute transaction but only rely on queries, what will be logged in the transaction log?

Thanks.

Comment: The transaction log doesn't log any type of query. This just logs the operations that physically change the data files with sufficient detail of the change to allow the operation to be rolled back. All statements in SQL Server Execute in a transaction context regardless of whether you explicitly create one or not. By default if you don't create one each statement gets its own transaction that operates in autocommit mode

Answer (score 0):

Read operations(SELECT queries) are **NOT LOGGED** into transaction log.
Write operations are **LOGGED** into Transaction log.

[More information on Transaction log architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Every SQL Server database has a transaction log that records all
> transactions and the database modifications that are made by each
> transaction. The transaction log is a critical component of the
> database and, if there is a system failure, the transaction log might
> be required to bring your database back to a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

No matter you explicitly used transaction context or not SQL Server logged all.

> Every SQL Server database has a transaction log that records all
> transactions and the database modifications made by each transaction.
> The transaction log is a critical component of the database. If there
> is a system failure, you will need that log to bring your database
> back to a consistent state.
> [The Transaction Log (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

But you can define the recovery model to control how SQL Server uses this feature.

> The "Simple" recovery model is the most basic recovery model for SQL Server. > >
> Every transaction is still written to the transaction log,
> but once the transaction is complete and the data has been written to
> the data file the space that was used in the transaction log file is
> now re-usable by new transactions.

[SQL Server Simple Recovery Model](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/4/sql-server-simple-recovery-model/)

There are two more types of of transaction logs: Full and Bulklog.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think a non-modifying transaction is not recorded at all

Comment: Select queried doesn't modify the data and there is nothing to rollback. So, those should not be recorded.

Comment: Which means that `that records all transactions` is incorrect documentation by Microsoft